# How to implement cluster of points with using BaiduMap SDK?

Tags: android, baidu-map

For my Chinese users, I need to use baidu maps in my app, but i don't understand how to implement clustering using BaiduSdk. There's no any utils like in a android-maps-utils. Perhaps someone can advise libs to implement clustering for BaiduMaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was package com.baidu.mapapi.clusterutil for working with clusters. But since version 3.7.3 they had removed it from library. You can take zip with cluster utils [here](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1gfx6Wxl#list/path=%2F) and put in your project.

Comment: Also, you can download sample with the newest sdk version, and take it from there. http://lbsyun.baidu.com/index.php?title=androidsdk